# What does nextInt do with the Scanner class in this code?

Tags: java, loops, do-loops

I had a question for class that I had to answer.

> Write a do loop that reads integers and computes their sum. Stop when reading a zero or the same  value twice in a row. For example, if the input is 1 2 3 4 4, then the sum is 14 and the loop stops. As another example, if the input is 4 5 1 0, then the sum is 10 and the loop stops. >

and the correct code was this.

```
    public static void integerCompute() {
        Scanner numberScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int x = 0; // Variable to keep track of user input
        int sum = 0; // Variable to keep track of sum
        int before; // Variable to check previously entered number
        
        do {
            before = x;
            System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
            x = numberScanner.nextInt(); // What does this do?
            sum += x;
        } while (x != 0 && before != x);

        System.out.println("Sum is: " + sum);
    }
```

In this loop, what does the `x = numberScanner.nextInt()` instruction do?

Comment: This `next.Int()` function is return integer value from your input.

Comment: And it will leave a dangling new line in the stream and if not consumed, will cause a exception if your try and use `nextInt` again

Comment: It waits for the user to type input and press enter, then it returns the next int from whatever they typed in.  If they typed multiple ints separated by spaces, then those numbers would be extracted in turn by the loop without requiring enter. It would only wait for enter to be pressed if there was no int waiting in the input stream.

Answer (score 0):

`numberScanner` is going to read each integer from `System.in` because it knows each number is separated by whitespace. `numberScanner.nextInt()` is saying "read me the integer that comes next." For example, if the input is "5 10 15 20", the first time `numberScanner.nextInt()` is called, `x` will be equal to 5. Call it one more time, and `x` will be equal to 10. When you run out of numbers, calling `nextInt()` will fail because there are no more numbers available (you can check if there are any more numbers by checking if `numberScanner.hasNext()` is equal to true or false).